# svn crashed (the server was destroyed), how can I rebuild repository in terms of the locale source code?

Tags: svn, xcode4, restore

Unfortunately, my svn server's disk was destroyed and all the code is missing. I set up a svn server with a new pc. Now I wanna to know if I can restore the repository in terms of the locale source codes on my client pc. And if it's possible, how should I do? Thanks. (BTW, my svn client is Xcode 4.2)

Comment: I suggest that you use one of free cloud base svn sites. In any case BACKUP

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to recover your SVN server and your repositories? Do you have a backup? Some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I have no backup and I do not want to recover the old SVN server, instead I wanna to create a new SVN server, then migrate my source codes to the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simple if your sources are in a single machine (an not scattered, which makes thinks difficult but not unfeasible...)
On a clean server:
Install subversion
Create a new repository with svnadmin create such as:

```
svnadmin create /some/path/myrepo
```

Your client system must also have subversion installed, and a protocol to use must be chosen, I prefer svn+ssh.

From your client, if your sources are under something like ./sources, use svn import such as in:

```
svn import sources/ svn+ssh://subversion.server.com/some/path/myrepo
```

This would import & commit all your sources into the repository, and you would be set to go...

Hope this helps...

Comment: And better implement passwordless ssh logins (via keys) to get rid of it asking for credentials every time you operate on the repository.